# Postgres function - resolve field with fallback

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, hasura

I have a table called `Listing` with fields `type` + `typeCustom` where type is a strict selection of values and when type is set to value "custom" I want to be able to dynamically resolve this as whatever is in my `typeCustom`-field.

```
SELECT 
   (CASE WHEN "type" = 'custom' THEN "typeCustom" ELSE "type" END) as "typeResolved"
FROM "Listing"
```

My naive way and quick googling tells me I should do something like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Listing_typeResolved(Listing_row "Listing")
RETURNS TEXT 
LANGUAGE sql
STABLE AS $$
  SELECT (CASE WHEN "type" = 'custom' THEN "typeCustom" ELSE "type" END)
$$
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Listing"
LINE 5:   SELECT (CASE WHEN "Listing"."type" = 'custom' THEN "Listin...
                            ^
```

Side-note: I'm using Hasura so I want to do this in order to expose a [computed field](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/computed-fields.html).

Comment: why are you using `"` ? remove it and should work fine.

Comment: It doesn't work either - AFAIK I need to when having tables that aren't all lowercase. But with that logic my `SELECT`-example wouldn't work either.

When removing quotes I get "ERROR: type listing does not exist".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
create function "Listing_typeResolved"(arg_type text, arg_typecustom text) returns text as
$$
 select case when arg_type = 'custom' then arg_type else arg_typecustom end;
$$
language sql immutable strict;
```

and then you can use it in queries like this

```
select "Listing_typeResolved"("type", "typeCustom") as "typeResolved" from "Listing";
```

to encapsulate the type resolution logic (no matter how simple it is) in a function.

Please consider a completely different approach - create/use a view:

```sql
create view "ListingV" as 
  select case when "type" = 'custom' then "typeCustom" else "type" end as "typeResolved",
  <other columns and clauses>
  from "Listing";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is beautiful, but unfortunately, hasura only allows me to put in 1 input argument in the function. But I might do a view..

Comment: I'm pretty sure hasura lets you add multiple arguments per function. What problem did you run into with adding more than one argument to a function?